How can I resolve a .NET Core web app that hangs on App.Run()
I am struggling with a .NET Core app. It worked some time ago, but now it keeps hanging without any changes made to it.
I tried waiting for a long time, but to no avail.
While debugging, I paused the execution and found out that it is stuck on the following code:
[UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser")]
public static bool Wait(object obj, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(obj, nameof(obj));
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfLessThan(millisecondsTimeout, -1, nameof(millisecondsTimeout));
    return ObjWait(millisecondsTimeout, obj);
}

Do you have any suggestions to make it work again?

I suggest you could using the debug dialog to capture the dumps and analysis it, just with this code we don't know why this happened.
